# How to solve Django Rest API Import "drf_yasg" could not be resolved

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, swagger, swagger-ui

```
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi
```

In the settings.py file, I add 'drf_yasg',

Im Using the Vscode... Here I'm trying to add Swagger but I got an unexpected problem

**Import "drf_yasg.views" could not be resolved**

[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jiXK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your virutal environment correctly.

If you are using VSCode, follow the process:

1. press `ctrl + shift + p` in Windows (or `cmd + shift + p` in MacOS).
2. Type "Python: Select Interpreter"
3. Choose the appropriate the virtual environment that you are using (either if you are using `venv`, `pipenv` or `poetry` etc).